# Which Nomu is more powerful, USJ Nomu or Hood?

Tags: my-hero-academia

The Ultra Analysis book only gives stats for Hood Nomu. 6/6 in power 5/6 in speed. Neither the Ultra Analysis book nor the Ultra Archive book gives stats for USJ Nomu, the one who fought All Might.

USJ Nomu had super strenght, super speed, super regeneration and shock absorption.

Hood has Muscle augmentation and stored power to increase his attacks (apparently 2 different quirks) , super speed, super regeneration, storage (it stores several other nomus in his body, apparently up to 9) , mounted jets for flying, and transforming arms which allows him to shapeshift his arms for attacks, it's ranked as high-end which is supposed to be also more intelligent, even though it doesnt seem to have shock absorption.

I'm not aware if there is more information in audio books or anything about them.

Which one is supposed to be more powerful, USJ Nomu or Hood?

Answer (score 1):

There are three categories of [**Nomu**](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Nomu) up until now in BnHA:

**Low-End Nomu** like the ones at Kamino. Low-End Nomu serve as foot soldiers and can overpower minor Pro Heroes. These Nomu are light in color and possess a multitude of Quirks as well as enhanced physical strength.

**Mid-End Nomu** like the ones at USJ. Mid-End Nomu can contend with the top Pro Heroes. These Nomu are generally black in color and possess the Super Regeneration Quirk and are even stronger than low-end Nomu.

**High-End Nomu** like Hood. High-End Nomu are intelligent Nomu that completely outclass the other Nomu. They possess abilities that can even overpower the top Pro Heroes, including up to six different Quirks.

So Hood is the strongest Nomu so far...

> And in the latest chapters it is shown that there are other High-End
>  Nomu being made.